# Create dashboard views that are based off of current date (ie. show resource overview for next 2 months)

Tags: ms-project

I'm attempting to create a report that is based off the current date. So, for example, creating a line graph that shows total work for all resources for the next 2 months. It would be very similar to the resource overview dashboard, but it wouldn't be pulling in data from the entire project.

The 'Resource Usage' view below has been very helpful, as it would be visual aids based on the hour allocations below. 
[image]

We can create a graph like the one below in the reporting module, I would like the graph to only look at the next 2 months (instead of the entire project duration). 
[image]

The goal is to look at capacity and future work allocation to easily look at resource availability to aid in assigning future tasks.

Thoughts? Tips? Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the built-in Report capability in MS Project 2016. Try modifying the Progress Versus Cost chart in the Cost Overview report.

Comment: All the information that I'm looking for is there, I would just like the data to automatically filter to the next 2 months (instead of the entire project duration).

Comment: Sorry, just saw this. All you have to do is build a custom filter, then apply that to the objects in the report. Use a flag field with a formula to restrict the data to just the next two months, then incorporate that flag in the filter.